# Node.js Discord.Js Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot. When we asked about an error, the bot gives an answer about that error. But when I get MySQL Data, i'm trying post it to Discord but it saying `undefined`.

Could you please help me?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require("./ayarlar.json");
const mysql = require('mysql');

var baglanti = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'hatabot'
});

baglanti.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log("baglanti basarili")
client.on('message', msg => {

    baglanti.query("SELECT * from hatalar WHERE hata_komut LIKE "+'%'+msg.content+'%',function(err,sonuc){
 
      console.log(msg.content+" kelimesine ait\n\n"+sonuc+"\n\nsonucu bulundu");
    });
});
});


client.login(ayarlar.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries return arrays, so that is why plain `result` or in your case `sonuc` will return array, and for this reason won't work. Also it might have 0 results, so you need to check that first

```js
baglanti.query("SELECT * FROM hatalar WHERE hata_komut LIKE "+'%'+msg.content+'%',function(err,sonuc){
     if(sonuc.length > 0){
     //Check if there is any rows
     console.log(sonuc[0].column);
     }
});
```

So to dive deeper;

As the query returns array, you need to choose which one of them, `sonuc[0]` is the first item in the array. The second thing I wrote there is the actual column of the table so let's say you have database with `id, user, email` columns and you want to display the user column, you would do `sonuc[0].user`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didnt complate somethings in my had. İf ı try like you sad Im getting type error because it cant read "undefined"s lenght.And even I wrote the keyword it not answering me with results.